# Encoding issue in .NET

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have a requirement to encode and decode Japanese characters. I tried in JAVA and it worked fine with "Cp939" encoding but am unable to find that encoding in .NET. The 932 encoding doesn't encode all the characters and so i need to find out a way of implementing 939 encoding in .NET.

Java Code :

```
convStr = new String(str8859_1.getBytes("Cp037"), "Cp939");
```

.NET :

```
bytesConverted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(37),
                                  Encoding.GetEncoding(932), bytesConverted);
// This result is a junk of characters and is totally different
// from the expected output 'ﾆﾂﾎﾟﾝﾊﾞ'
convStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytesConverted);
```

Answer (score 2):

The encoded bytes are in the encoding 932, so why are you using the encoding 1252 when you convert the encoded bytes to a string?

The following should work:

```
bytesConverted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(37),
                                  Encoding.GetEncoding(932), bytesConverted);
// This result is a junk of characters and is totally different
// from the expected output 'ﾆﾂﾎﾟﾝﾊﾞ'
convStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetString(bytesConverted);
```

Comment: Am trying to replicate java code. As you see below             convStr = new String(str8859_1.getBytes("Cp037"), "Cp939");        The new String() by default converts into 1252 decoding. Hence am trying to do the same. If i decode with 932, japanese characters are not getting recognized. I need to follow this way and don't have 939 in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

is this an error or just how you typed it ?

```
bytesConverted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(37), 
    Encoding.GetEncoding(932), bytesConverted);
```

should be:

```
bytesConverted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(37), 
    Encoding.GetEncoding(939), bytesConverted);
```

Surely ?

Comment: If i give Encoding.GetEncoding(939), it throws error stating that 'Unsupported Encoding'. So not able to encode in 939.